# Get the RGB value of each pixel from bmp file

Tags: c, image-processing, bmp

So I have a bmp file, and I want to extract the details of rgb for every pixel of the image.

I read somewhere that the following would do this for me

```
int main(){
int image[100][3]; // first number here is 100 pixels in my image, 3 is for RGB     values
 FILE *streamIn;
 int i;
 streamIn = fopen("./t.bmp", "r");
 if (streamIn == (FILE *)0){
    printf("File opening error ocurred. Exiting program.\n");
    return 0;
 }

  int byte;
  int count = 0;
  for(i=0;i<54;i++) byte = getc(streamIn);  // strip out BMP header

  for(i=0;i<100;i++){    // foreach pixel
     image[i][2] = getc(streamIn);  // use BMP 24bit with no alpha channel
     image[i][1] = getc(streamIn);  // BMP uses BGR but we want RGB, grab byte-by-byte
     image[i][0] = getc(streamIn);  // reverse-order array indexing fixes RGB issue...
     //printf("[%d,%d,%d] ",image[i][0],image[i][1],image[i][2]);
     if(image[i][0]==255 && image[i][1]==255 && image[i][2]==255)
        printf("B");
     else if(image[i][0]==0 && image[i][1]==0 && image[i][2]==0)
        printf("W");
     else{
        printf("[%d,%d,%d]",image[i][0],image[i][1],image[i][2]);
        //return 0;
     }
  }

  fclose(streamIn);
  return 0;
 }
```

Now considering my bmp file is 10*10 pixel, will the above method work?

**Edit** I have added an answer, maybe that can help someone. Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried it? Was it correct?

Comment: This program assumes 24bit BMP pixel data and makes an assumption about the size of the header. Even though this is/may be typical, I suggest you investigate how the [BMP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) works first. You may not be working with exactly the same file format (even though it is likely).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg well I had a jpg with me, and I converted it to bmp using imagemagick using `convert <jpgfile> -threshold xx% <bmpfile>` with the threshold applied. I thought all the pixels will have value 000 or 255 255 255, but some of them had different values.

Comment: If you've tried this and it didn't work, you should be reform your question to reflect that and the specific problem you are having. At the moment this is very vague. Also, you'll need to be a bit more clear about "different values". Were they greater than 255?

Comment: I suggest you read more about the [file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). The headers and data before the actual pixel data can be anywhere between 32 and 144 bytes, _at least_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code sample is very crude and I wouldn't recommend doing it this way.

However, if you insist, there's a rule you need to know about: every row is padded to an exact multiple of 4 bytes. In your case a row is 10*3 or 30 bytes, so it gets 2 extra bytes of padding. If you don't account for that as you read the file, you'll be off.

Comment: @padding is on the right side or the left? And what is the length of header?

Comment: @Kraken on the right. I don't know the exact size of the header but the value you're using doesn't seem out of line.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the padding information, else I would have been lost trying to figure out those spurious results.

Answer (score 0):

So I created three different bmp files from three different jpg, each with different number of pixels, and here is what I found out.

1. The header info, or basically, the color of each pixel, starts appearing after 138 bytes of data.
2. Mark Random correctly suggested about the padding, that each row has to have a multiple of 4 as the number of bytes.
3. The padded bytes, get the value 0.

The above conclusions are based on the instances that I took, and in no way are generalised. Hope it helps.

Comment: were you able to extract the three channels?